# Laptop battery uptime monitor

Tags: laptop, battery, statistics

Is there any way to measure what sort of uptime/active usage I get out of a given battery charge; that is, how long do I get actually using the laptop between full charges. I'd like it to be a cumulative figure whether the laptop has been shutdown, hibernated etc in between. I know there is benchmark type software that will give a figure over a single session, but I'm looking for more real world use stats.  I work in Windows and Linux.

Comment: DO you use a lenovo laptop?? If yes, then lenovo Energy Manager should be pre-installed and it has some pretty sick features...

Comment: I do actually, but it uses Lenovo Power Manager (seems to be a different app from Energy Management). Power manager does not provide the info I'm looking for, so I will check out Energy Management (is it a new version of what is basically power manager?)

Answer (score 1):

Try BatteryInfoView. It's a pretty simple little utility to use.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at this. At the risk of answering my own question, i also found Battery Uptime Monitor (http://bum.codeplex.com/) which on the surface appears to do exactly what I want. However it hasn't been updated in some time and seems a tad unstable (won't stay running for me)

Answer (score 0):

DO you use a lenovo laptop?? If yes, then lenovo Energy Manager should be pre-installed and it has some pretty sick features...

It should be downloadable from Lenovo Updates or Lenovo Companion...
[image]